# Hotel Reservation (LodgingReservation) card not showing in Google Now

Tags: android, json, gmail, google-schemas, google-now

I've been trying to integrate a Google schema (LodgingReservation schema) in my company's hotel booking confirmation e-mails, in order to make corresponding hotel reservation cards appear in Google Now/Google Search, as specified in the following Google documentation :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation

I've sent a test e-mail containing the JSON markup multiple times to my Gmail account, opened the e-mail, then refreshed my Google Now app's feed multiple times, but no Reservation Card showing there.

I do get some other types of cards, such as local weather info, event reminders from my calendar, etc. I checked the settings on my Google account and Android phone multiple times, tried to use different accounts and phones from my colleagues, but it won't show ANYWHERE.

HOWEVER :

- Viewing the source from the e-mail, I was able to confirm that the expected markup was there, and even managed to validate it using the following Google tool : https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/
- Using my Google account, I'm able to see that my Google Card history contains a "travel" type card, supposedly received today, and that appears on every phone/Google account I've tested, a few seconds after the booking confirmation e-mail was sent

Based on those informations, I assume the card is recognized somehow by my account, but I don't get why it wouldn't show in the gNow feed ...

Would someone have an idea about that ?

Here is the markup I've sent in the e-mail :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "LodgingReservation",
        "reservationNumber": "872914",
        "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
        "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Max Mustermann"
        },
        "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
            "name": "Verkaufshotel Blaue Linde",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "Industriestra&amp;#223;e 27",
                "addressLocality": "Offenburg",
                "addressRegion": "Ortenau",
                "postalCode": "77656",
                "addressCountry": "Deutschland"
            },
            "telephone": "+49 781 310 55 0"
        },
        "checkinDate": "2015-11-20T11:00:00-08:00",
        "checkoutDate": "2015-11-23T11:00:00-08:00"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it's possible you're in a country where Google Now is not supported. You can find the list of countries where you can turn on Google Now here: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6245953?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

@Joffrey Quillet I've tested your markup and was able to generate a Now card, however, I did change the checkinDate and checkoutDate during my test:

```
    "checkinDate": "2015-11-23T13:30:00-08:00",
    "checkoutDate": "2015-11-24T11:00:00-08:00"
```

I have a feeling you're located in a area that doesn't support hotel reservation cards. Per this [documentation](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6245953?hl=en), "*Even if you can turn on Google Now in your country, you might not see every type of Now card.*"

Here is my result using your markup example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You might well be right ! I'm using it from Germany (since my company is German), and now that I think of it, it used to work before Google updated their terms and conditions recently.

The only explanation I could see is that the Hotel Reservation Cards are not supported in Germany anymore.

In any case, thanks to you I now know the markup is probably not at fault, so I only have to test it in another country (France for instance) and see what it does. If it's not too personal, would you mind telling me which country you ran your test from ?

Comment: @jaykyuu I see. My testing was done in the US, I do see that France (Metropolitan only) is enabled for Now cards.